# Matrizes Strings

Tags: java, string

Em um exercicio do livro "use a cabeça java", pede para declarar 3 matrizes de string, mas quando eu coloco o codigo na ide fica dando um erro de tipos incompatíveis string para String[] alguém sabe o porquê???

```
package exercicios;

/**
 *
 * @author DANIEL
 */
public class Exercicios {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] lista1 =  ("24/7", "Varias Camadas","B-to-B","Todos ganham","front-end","baseado na web","Difundido");

       String[] lista2 = ("habilitado","adesivo","valor agregado","orientado","central","distribuido","agrupado");

       String[] lista3 = ("processo","ponto máximo","solução","arquitetura","habilitação no núcleo","estrátegia");

       int n1 = lista1.length;
       int n2 = lista2.length;
       int n3 = lista3.length;

       int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * lista1);
    }

}
```

Comment: No livro o literal dos *arrays* está com parenteses ou chaves?

Comment: Sim, `String` é uma coisa, `String[]` é outra. O primeiro é apenas um tipo, o segundo é a forma de declarar um array que suporta apenas o tipo String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A inicialização do array deve ser feita com chaves, não parênteses.

Declare assim:

```
String[] lista1 = {"24/7", "Varias Camadas","B-to-B","Todos ganham","front-end","baseado na web","Difundido"};

 String[] lista2 = {"habilitado","adesivo","valor agregado","orientado","central","distribuido","agrupado"};

 String[] lista3 = {"processo","ponto máximo","solução","arquitetura","habilitação no núcleo","estrátegia"};
```

Comment: nossa era com chaves,não tinha percebido valeu ai pessoal :)